# Zero DateTime Behavior with Dizzle JDBC Driver

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, drizzle

I have a MySQL database connected to my application with the **Drizzle MySQL-connector**.
This database has a table with a DateTime column that can have the value `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Now I want to get some data:

```
TypedQuery<UserData> query = em.createQuery("FROM UserData", UserData.class);
    List<UserData> result = query.getResultList();
```

This throws the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not parse column as timestamp, was: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
```

With the **mysql-connector-java** you can convert `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` to `null` the following way in your datasource.xml:

```
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</connection-url>
```

The Drizzle Connector doesn't have that connection-option.
Is there any other way to handle this zeroDateTimeBehavior with the Drizzle driver?